# 'int' object not callable from array

Tags: python, arrays, astronomy

It seems like 'int' object not callable error is a common issue, however, I can't find any solutions that are applicable to my case. I am trying to call on an element from an array in an equation only to be met with this error.

```
K = array((a,x,y), float)
mu_alpha = ((K[1,54])-(K[1,0]))/((K[0,54])-(K[0,0])) # total change in RA over time (0 days to 986.175 days)
mu_delta = ((K[2,54])-(K[2,0]))/((K[0,54])-(K[0,0])) # # total change in DEC over time (0 days to 986.175 days)
print(mu_alpha, 'arcsec/yr')
print(mu_delta, 'arcsec/yr')

mu = sqrt(((mu_alpha)**2)*(cos**2(K[2,54])) + (mu_delta)**2)
print('total proper motion =', mu, 'arcsec/yr')
```

I can tell that the error comes from the cos^2 term where I call on the element as the code works when I remove it. How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: `2(K[2,54]))` is invalid. Did you mean `2 * (K[2,54]))`?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I implemented it and in that case the error is: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'numpy.ufunc' and 'int'

Comment: I think what you actually want to square is the result of the cosine function. Try `((cos(K[2,54]))**2)`